# Getting name from comma-separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two SQL Server tables, `EmployeeMst` and `EmployeeHistory`

`EmployeeMst` is my master table, and `EmployeeHistory` is my record table.

I store comma-separated values in `EmployeeHistory`

Now I want to get employee names with use of a T-SQL query

My table `EmployeeMst`

```
EmpNo   EmpName
---------------------
1       abc
2       xyz
3       apple
4       banan
5       apk
6       ico
7       exe
8       botle
9       dev
10      tbl
11      col
12      fun
13      dbo
14      xnb
15      png
16      jpgn
17      pngns
18      dknd
19      dnckd
20      dnicnd
```

`EmployeeHistory`:

```
EmpYear    EmpNo
---------------------------------
2010       1,2,3,10,11,12,13
2011       1,2,3,4,5,6,16,17,18
```

Now i want output as below

OUTPUT:

```
EmpYear  EmpNo   EmpName
2010      1       abc
2010      2       xyz
2010      3       apple
2010      10      tbl
2010      11      col
2010      12      fun
2010      13      dbo
2011      1       abc
2011      2       xyz
2011      3       apple
2011      4       banan
2011      5       apk
2011      6       ico
2011      16      jpgn
2011      17      pngns
2011      18      dknd
```

There are so many comma-separated values in `EmpNo column`

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b3c9)

Comment: i understand, but i can't get output from other question.

Comment: You can if you put the output of the function into a temp/variable table and then use that in your final select

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: i am not able to do this. if you know than please share

Comment: What are you having problems with? Have you looked at the multiple different answers showing different ways of doing it? Go writing the code and then come back with a specific issue that you have, not with a "write this code for me"

Comment: if you know the answer than put this query in my sqlfiddle.

Comment: That is not what SO is for, we don't write code for others, we show you what you could do and let you figure it out and by that learn how to. If you want code written, pay someone for it

Comment: Gosh - when are programmers going to **stop** violating even the **First Normal Form** of database design by stuffing everything into **comma-separated** column values?!?!?!?! This is the devil's work .....

Comment: Gosh - when are programmer's going to **stop** violating even the **First Normal Form** of database design by stuffing everything into **comma-separated** column values?!?!?!?! This is the devil's work .....

Comment: i know this is devil's work. but this work is not done by me. it's my senior's work. and now i handle this old project.

Comment: Mr. marc_s,  i know this question is duplicate but no answer is perfect as per my output.

Comment: Try this method:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b3c9/4

Comment: @ Vasily,  thanks for positive answer. i got solution another way you also try 
Select EmployeeHistory.EmpYear,EmployeeMst.EmpNo,EmployeeMst.EmpName from EmployeeHistory
Inner Join EmployeeMst  On
  CharIndex(',' + EmployeeMst.EmpNo + ',', ',' + EmployeeHistory.EmpNo + ',') > 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]  
( 
    -- Add the parameters for the function here 
    @myString nvarchar(max), 
    @deliminator nvarchar(10) 
) 
RETURNS  
@ReturnTable TABLE  
( 
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here 
    [part] [nvarchar](max) NULL 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
        Declare @iSpaces int 
        Declare @part nvarchar(max) 

        --initialize spaces 
        Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0) 
        While @iSpaces > 0 

        Begin 
            Select @part = substring(@myString,0,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)) 

            Insert Into @ReturnTable(part) 
            Select @part 

    Select @myString = substring(@mystring,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)+ len(@deliminator),len(@myString) - charindex(' ',@myString,0)) 


            Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0) 
        end 

        If len(@myString) > 0 
            Insert Into @ReturnTable 
            Select @myString 

    RETURN  
END
```

then

```
select part from  SplitString('a,b,c,d,e,f,g',',')
```